# What is the relationship between DbEntityValidationResult and ValidationResult?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, validation

Can someone explain the relationship between `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult` classes?

The `IValidatableObject` is dealing with `ValidationResult` objects that can be used to validate an object that is using Data Annotations. At the same time, when using an Entity Framework DataContext to store an object, `DbEntityValidationResult` objects are used to report validation errors. So I wonder about the exact relationship between the two. Are `DbEntityValidationResult` objects only used when actually interacting with a database?

And is the `ComponentModel` validation used by EF internally or are the two completely independent except that they both rely on Data Annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult` - **is used for objects that are using Data Annotations.** `ValidationResult` class contains a property with names of properties the error applies to.

Basically Entity framework use `System.ComponentModel` for validation inside its own methods.

`System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult` - **is used only by Entity Framework**. **DbValidationError** contains error for one property of whole validated object.

`DbEntityValidationResult` is actually **a part of EntityFramework assembly**.

When Entity Framework validate data (that happens in `Validation` method of `ValidatableObjectValidator` class) in converts `IEnumerable<DataAnnotaion.ValidationResult>` to `IEnumerable<DbValidationError>`:

```
foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
{
    if (validationResult == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    // let's treat null or empty .MemberNames the same way as one undefined (null) memberName
    var memberNames = validationResult.MemberNames == null || !validationResult.MemberNames.Any()
                            ? new string[] { null }
                            : validationResult.MemberNames;

    foreach (var memberName in memberNames)
    {
        yield return new DbValidationError(memberName ?? propertyName, validationResult.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

**As a result for each name in `ValidationResult.MemberNames` one `DbValidationError` will be created (with some exceptions for special cases like null or empty .MemberNames or null names in the .MemberNames)**

Links to sources:

[ValidatableObjectValidator.cs](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Internal/Validation/ValidatableObjectValidator.cs)

[DbHelpers.cs](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Internal/DbHelpers.cs)

Comment: Do you know if the ComponentModel validation is used by EF internally or are the two completely independent except that they both rely on Data Annotations?

Comment: I think they are independent, but let me check.

Comment: EF use ComponentModel inside own validation. You can find description in my updated answer.

Comment: Updated links to those sources: 
https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/99c172bc465492fa37f9efa07900653975ec79b4/src/EntityFramework/Internal/Validation/ValidatableObjectValidator.cs
https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/99c172bc465492fa37f9efa07900653975ec79b4/src/EntityFramework/Internal/DbHelpers.cs